# Autohotkey macro to switch mouse position between multiple screens

Tags: autohotkey, multiple-monitors

I just want to put this here.
I needed a macro that moves the mouse cursor to the other monitor.
But on the same relative position proportional to the screen resolution.
And not getting stuck at the border.
And not clicking something in the process.

Ctrl+MiddleMouseButton moves the cursor to the next screen now and should work with any number of screens and different resolutions.
I can test it with 2 screens only though.

Answer (score 0):

```
^MButton::
  SysGet, monitors, MonitorCount

  SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
  SysGet, MonitorPrimary, MonitorPrimary
  
  current := 0
  Loop, %MonitorCount%
  {
    SysGet, Monitor, Monitor, %A_Index%
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    if (  (MouseX >= MonitorLeft) && (MouseX < MonitorRight) && (MouseY >= MonitorTop) && (MouseY < MonitorBottom) )
    {
      current := A_Index
      currentRX := (MouseX - MonitorLeft) / (MonitorRight - MonitorLeft)
      currentRY := (MouseY - MonitorTop) / (MonitorBottom - MonitorTop)
      break
    }
  }
  next := current + 1
  
  if (next > MonitorCount)
    next := 1
  SysGet, Monitor, Monitor, %next%
  
  newX := MonitorLeft + currentRX*(MonitorRight - MonitorLeft)
  newY := MonitorTop + currentRY*(MonitorBottom - MonitorTop)
  
  DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", newX, "int", newY)
  DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", newX, "int", newY)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about the cursor keeping it's relative position and just jump to the middle of the next screen use this (alt+middlemouse in this example):

```
!MButton::
  SysGet, monitors, MonitorCount

  SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
  SysGet, MonitorPrimary, MonitorPrimary
  
  current := 0
  Loop, %MonitorCount%
  {
    SysGet, Monitor, Monitor, %A_Index%
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    if (  (MouseX >= MonitorLeft) && (MouseX < MonitorRight) && (MouseY >= MonitorTop) && (MouseY < MonitorBottom) )
    {
      current := A_Index
      break
    }
  }
  next := current + 1
  if (next > MonitorCount)
    next := 1

  SysGet, Monitor, Monitor, %next%
  newX := MonitorLeft + 0.5*(MonitorRight - MonitorLeft)
  newY := MonitorTop + 0.5*(MonitorBottom - MonitorTop)
  
  DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", newX, "int", newY)
  DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", newX, "int", newY)
return
```